# how to add image in box2d js

Tags: javascript, jbox2d

I want to add image in objects of box2d js .for eg I want to add a real soccer image in the circle shape of box2d js.

I have tried to insert image by watching videos on youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrMExe93O1U&t=225s and reading websites : http://www.jeremyhubble.com/box2d.html  ,but i didn't got the answer.

In that video they use bitmap to insert the image .
And I really didn't understood the video.

I watched the video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrMExe93O1U&t=225s

If possible please send me the working code in js format.

Comment: Hi @Animesh. No one is going to watch the video or go through the website. Please provide your code where you are facing issue. Then people can help you to point out the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for advising me . I would like to put the code but I don't know how to write the code of image and I didn't understood the box2d well . So next time I will sure eleminate those mistakes and will try to keep code .